# how to combine Webdriver, Appium and soup in one framework

Tags: java, web-services, selenium, testing, appium

I need to put Web sites testing , Mobile testing  and Webservice testing in single Framework. Means single framework will perform all these type of testing.

As the configuration is define in environment file (.property file ) the framework should get ready to perform relevant  testing

Using environment:-
testNG, selenium - grid,
Window , Appium , Webdriver , etc

Can anyone please provide me guideline?

Comment: Selenium and Appium test you can integrate easily in single framework as you can write wrapper classes. For API automation you can user rest assured. One additional point : to run test using appium you need to start appium which you have to handle in your framework .

Comment: Thanks , Appium and webdriver integration in single work is ok But please update me with integration of API testing in framework

Answer (score 0):

Integration of API testing in framework :

+Appium utility
+Selinium utility
-API
  - RestAPIService using HTTPClient
  - ResponseParser - ObjectMapper
  - DataSource similar to UI framework

+TestClass
 -Here you can call you Appium/Selenium/API methods

For Api integration you can create one RestService class in that you can create wrapper methods getRequest(url, header) , postRequest(url, header) , putRequest(url, header) and deleteRequest(url, header). For response parsing you can use available json parser. and data you can take from same source which you are using in UI automation.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use all the libraries and create a wrapper around it.
2. Create interfaces which uses the libraries and implement them in your class.
3. Since all that you mentioned are open source jars, it should not be a problem to integrate them.

You can [check here](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project)! This is an open source framework and they have integrated Appium, Jersey client and Selenium. If you are facing specific issue, please reply I will try to reproduce it from my end :)